# Generating random points on the circumference of a circle (python)

Tags: python, random

I was wondering how can i efficiently get the coordinate of random points on a circular locus.
I tried the equation of the circle where (h,k) is the center, r is the radius and (x,k) is the randomly generated point.

(x−h)^2 + (y−k)^2 = r^2

I tried checking each randomly generated point whether it satisfies the equation, but this method is highly inefficient. 
Is there any way I can implement it in python?

Comment: Hmm. What kind randomness do you need? Should every point on the circle curve be equally likely or do you require there a difference in likelyhood between points on the curve? Side note: If not for rounding errors, your current method has basically zero chance of hitting the circle.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use trigonometry?

```
from math import pi, cos, sin
from random import random

def point(h, k, r):
    theta = random() * 2 * pi
    return h + cos(theta) * r, k + sin(theta) * r
```

Here is its use in a complete program:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from math import pi, cos, sin
from random import random

def point(h, k, r):
    theta = random() * 2 * pi
    return h + cos(theta) * r, k + sin(theta) * r

xy = [point(1,2,1) for _ in range(30)]

plt.scatter(*zip(*xy))
plt.grid(color='k', linestyle=':', linewidth=1)
plt.axes().set_aspect('equal', 'datalim')
plt.show()
```

And the result:

[image]

Comment: but what is `n`?

Comment: `n` is a mistake. I thought I'd return a list when I write the first line. Fixed.

Comment: Erm, `math.cos()` and `math.sin()` don't take degrees, they take radians, so you probably want `random.random() * 2.0 * math.pi`. As is, the sampling is skewed.

Comment: Yes, math.cos() and math.sin() functions will require radians. 2* math.pi*r worked. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, @dhke - fixed.

Comment: Why `h` and `k` instead of `x` and `y`?

Comment: @JoshGrinberg - Because that's what the original poster used: "the circle where `(h,k)` is the center,".